# Adding a network card to the modprobe file

Tags: arch-linux, internet, modprobe

I'm trying to setup an ADSL connection on an Arch Linux machine. I read the Arch wiki article on [Internet Access](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_Access), but I'm still confused -- how do I add my network card to the `modprobe` file?

Comment: its also known as DSL connection

Comment: My NIC card is Realtek RTL8168c

Comment: The RTL8168c looks like an ordinary (Ethernet) network card. Don't you have a DSL modem (maybe called a modem-router or DSL router or something like that)? In any case it's unlikely that you would need to use modprobe, most of the time the kernel will detect the hardware and automatically load the right driver.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_Access) you are pointing to, I find:

> "Most users of external modems or
>   those behind routers should consult
>   the [Configuring Network](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network) article
>   instead."

Have you tried that?

Comment: Hey, I already set up an ADSL connection so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, do you plug the phone cord directly into your PC? Otherwise, if you have a router, you don't need to do anything except configure your network correctly (that is, with the correct gateway -- for example 192.168.1.1).

To answer your question, they probably mean adding the module (driver) to `/etc/modules` (might be named differently on Arch), so that it is forced to load on boot (most modules are loaded automatically as their corresponding hardware is detected).